# Ruby - "bundle install" json gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, windows, rubygems

I am working on Windows 10. I successfully installed Ruby, MSYS2 and DevKit, but after trying to run the following command:

```
bundle install
```

it throws me an error

```
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried the solution with

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

but it still doesn't work for me. 
Does anybody knows how i can fix the error?

Comment: did you try `bundle update` then `bundle install`?

Comment: @AmrAdel No, i will try, hope it works ;)

Comment: What errors do you get from the Json geminstall?

Comment: Json 1.8 is an old gem you may have trouble to install on a recent Ruby version. Please see this similar case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307653/bundle-install-error-json-gem#comment87639105_50307653

Comment: @AmrAdel Yeah i tried first bundle update, but then i got error for do_sqlite3 gem

Comment: @Joe i fixed the json gem error, but now i got the error for some do_sqlite3 gem

Comment: @Maxence i fixed the json gem error, but now i got the error for some do_sqlite3 gem

Comment: I doubt the problem is ruby version or something,
Sometimes I remove what is inside GEMFILE.lock and run bundle install again, could  u try this?

Comment: @AmrAdel, i tried everything and still got this do_sqlite3 error. I also downloaded SQLite3 and place it in Ruby directory, but still nothing. Here is the image of an error: https://imgur.com/a/kbENwvm Please check it out. It happens when i try to run a "bundle update" command.

Comment: Add the errors you're getting to your post.